# Can't import scipy's io

Tags: python, scipy

I'm a real newbie to Python, so I've probably done some rookie mistake. But I can't seem to figure it out so I hope someone can help me out. I want to use Matlab(.mat)-files in Python. In order to do that I tried:

```
import scipy.io
```

which gives me the error:

> File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\io__init__.py", line 85, in 
>       from .matlab import loadmat, savemat, whosmat, byteordercodes
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab__init__.py", line 13, in 
>       from .mio import loadmat, savemat, whosmat
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\mio.py", line 12, in 
>       from .miobase import get_matfile_version, docfiller
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\miobase.py", line 22, in 
>       from scipy.misc import doccer
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\misc__init__.py", line 44, in 
>       from . import doccer
>       ImportError: cannot import name doccer

Don't understand this, what does "doccer" mean?

Interestingly, when I give it `import scipy` it seems to do OK. When I give it:
    `help(scipy.io)` 
it gives the error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'io'
```

But when I check the scipy folder it has another folder called io. Can anyone help me out? PS: I run Python 2.7.

Comment: `doccer` can't be some module. Did you import  both `scipy` and `scipy.io` ?

Comment: The error means Scipy is not installed correctly on your machine. What exactly is wrong is not clear from the information you give.

Comment: Well, I tried both but when I did scipy.io it gave me the error.

Comment: Should I reinstall it then?

Comment: yes you should re-install SciPy. Make sure that it's the correct version (32 bit/64 bit)

Comment: I give up now, tried everything and nothing works out. Gonna try installing Python all over again. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here you have to import your module which you will be using from `scipy.io` package
For eg. Lets say i am dealing with audio data and want `wavfile` module then i will do

```
import scipy.io.wavfile
sr,data = scipy.io.wavfile.read("xx")
```

here are all its modules

```
   ['FortranEOFError',
 'FortranFile',
 'FortranFormattingError',
 'byteordercodes',
 'harwell_boeing',
 'hb_read',
 'hb_write',
 'idl',
 'loadmat',
 'matlab',
 'mminfo',
 'mmio',
 'mmread',
 'mmwrite',
 'netcdf',
 'netcdf_file',
 'netcdf_variable',
 'readsav',
 'savemat',
 'whosmat']
```